# .zshrc git branch in prompt

Tags: git, zsh

I've got a simple but custom .zshrc that I'd like to populate the prompt with the git branch I'm currently on (when in a git repo). The code below seems to work, but one prompt behind where I'm actually at.

.zshrc:

```
#Prompt messing
    # Load colors for prompt
    autoload -U colors && colors
    # Load version control information
    autoload -Uz vcs_info
    precmd() {
        vcs_info
        if [[ -n ${vcs_info_msg_0_} ]]; then
            # allow check for changes
            zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
            #sets unstaged string to this
            zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' unstagedstr "!"
            #sets staged string to this
            zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' stagedstr "+"
            zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '%K{green}%u%k%K{cyan}%c%k'

            BRANCH=$(command git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
            PS1='%F{magenta}%7>>${BRANCH}%<<%f'
            PS1+='${vcs_info_msg_0_} %~; '
        else
            PS1='%~; '
        fi
    }
```

For example:

```
master ~/code/external-api; cd ..
master ~/code; 
~/code;
```

I would expect the second line there to not have the `master` in the prompt.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

After going to the trouble to enabling vcs_info, you've then got your own git branch implementation with the two lines assigning `$BRANCH`. Setting zstyles for `vcs_info` really doesn't need to be repeated every time `precmd()` runs. It is better to use `psvar` and `%v` instead of relying on the `PROMPT_SUBST` option. For example:

```
    PS1='%(V.%v .)%~; '
    autoload -U vcs_info
    zstyle … # all the zstyle commands from before
    precmd() {
      vcs_info
      psvar[1]="${vcs_info_msg_0_}"
    }
```

I also wouldn't bother with the `colors` function. Just using `%F{majenta}` works better. It is a holdover from many years ago before zsh had direct support and just sets variables with literal escape sequences.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](https://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/customize-zsh-prompt-with-vcs-info.html) you can do this with vcs_info.

```
# in your ~/.zshrc
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
precmd() {
    vcs_info
}

# Prompt setup
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}%# '

# Format the message
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' formats "%{$fg[grey]%}%s %{$reset_color%}%r/%S%{$fg[grey]%} %{$fg[blue]%}%b%{$reset_color%}%m%u%c%{$reset_color%} "
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the 'one prompt behind' problem, try adding this to `~/.zshrc`, after declaring the function:

```
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd precmd
```

The `precmd` function isn't a `precmd` function until you make it a `precmd` function :). A lot of folks have `oh-my-zsh` installed, and get the  `precmd` hook set that way, so this part isn't always documented.

To avoid confusion, it's often preferable to use a different name for the function:

```
function my_precmd {
  vcs_info
  ...
}
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd
```